# Difference between Office 365 Exchange and On Premise Exchange

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, office-365

I'm new to sharepoint, one of the interviewer as asked me this question? Could anyone let me know the exact difference and meaning on the same

Comment: Are you asking about SharePoint or Exchange?

Comment: Hi, @jpussacq, just want to understand those terms in detail along with their differences...can you guide me

Answer (score 0):

Exchange online is a cloud-based solution as part of Office 365, controlled by MSFT. A difference is one is a cloud-based solution and other is on prem.

On-prem exchange deployment, you will full control, less cost as user grow, No Dir Sync, all the data reside locally and integration with other application within organization easy.

Exchange Online give you peace of mind i.e no need to worry about the upgrade,excellent security, stability, functionality, scalability, Access anywhere, New features deployed quickly.

Please see below the comprehensive Comparision list of features.

[Comparing Exchange Online and Exchange Server 2013](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2012/09/19/comparing-exchange-online-and-exchange-server-2013.aspx)

[Exchange Server 2010 SP1 and Exchange Online (Office 365) Feature Comparison](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4160.exchange-server-2010-sp1-and-exchange-online-office-365-feature-comparison.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

OnPremise means the software is installed inside your premise , inside your company. Your admins will look after it , you will buy the full software and you have complete control over it.

Cloud Based( Online) means the software is hosted by a third party provider like Azure or Amazon. You do not need to buy the full software you can pay as you need.

From the question i did not get you want sharepoint or exchange. Assuming you asked for sharepoint. You can see from this link how to get access to online sharepoint using office 365 http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1091804/Learn-SharePoint-step-by-step-in-hours-Hour#On-premise_and_Office_365